# Type-safe Query builder for Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint, tinkerpop3

Is there a type-safe query builder for Gremlin? As of now we are building them by string concatenation hence not type-safe. I am looking for some thing similar to [CriteriaBuilder](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) in JPA.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but [Gremlin-Scala](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala) for Tinkerpop3 supports fully typesafe paths.

```
import gremlin.scala._
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory
def g = TinkerFactory.createModern.asScala

// select all labelled steps
g.V(1).as("a")
.outE.as("b")
.select
.toList
// returns a `(Vertex, Edge)` for each path
```

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of Gremlin-Scala ;)

Comment: plus one. Is Tinkerpop3 production ready? I am using 2.5 as it is the most recent released version. Also, is there a Java equivalent of this? we are a java shop.

Comment: @Pangea Tinkerpop3 is not production ready as of today - we have a release candidate but still making many big changes.. 
You could use Gremlin-Java direct (it's what Gremlin-Groovy and Gremlin-Scala are built on)